# Returned array contains a lot of "True" values

Tags: powershell

guys.
I writing a simple powershell script, and have strange behaviour of returning value.

```
function get-ResourcesForCsv {
    param([string]$Container)

    $Groups = Get-ADGroup -filter * -SearchBase $Container | 
            select-object Name | where-object { $_.Name -notlike "*`$All*" }
    $Resources = @()    
    foreach( $Group in $Groups ) {
        $Group.Name -match "((\w+)_)(.+)(_([RW]))"     
        $Resource = @{
            Name = $Matches[3]
            Access = $Matches[5]
            Group = $Group.Name
        }
        $Resources += New-Object PSObject -Property $Resource
    }
    write-host $Resources # Here's ok
    $Resources
}

function get-ResourcesForHtml {
    param([string]$Container)
    $Temp = get-ResourcesForCsv $Container
    write-host $Resources # Here's things goes terrible
    ...
}
```

When i check $Resources value - it's ok, when i check $Temp - size is doubled, and array contains a lot of "True" at the begining.

P.S. Sorry for my terrible english ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning the result of this match to any variable. I assume that you would add to $Resource if its matching your regex so:

```
if($Group.Name -match "((\w+)_)(.+)(_([RW]))" )
{
        $Resource = @{
            Name = $Matches[3]
            Access = $Matches[5]
            Group = $Group.Name
        }
        $Resources += New-Object PSObject -Property $Resource
}
```

You were assigning every return of cmdlet which is not assigned to variable or anyway handled from the function `get-ResourcesForCsv` to the variable `$Temp` including the result from matching the regex.

note: tested in my organization

Comment: Oh...
My main language is С++ and this behavior looks very illogical and strange. Thank you for opening my eyes.